java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key null (attempted merging values 0 and 1)
I am experimenting with the langchain4j extension for Quarkus and although my code seems straightforward, I just can't get it running and get the following error on building it "Build step io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor#handleAiServices threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key null (attempted merging values 0 and 1)"
This is my Rest Resource
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.*;

@RequestScoped
@Path("/translate")
public class TranslatorResource {
    @Inject TranslatorService translatorService;

    @POST
    public String translate(@FormParam("text") String text, @FormParam("destination") String destination) {
        return translatorService.translate(text, destination);
    }
}

This is my Agent
import dev.langchain4j.service.SystemMessage;
import dev.langchain4j.service.UserMessage;
import io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.RegisterAiService;

@RegisterAiService
public interface TranslatorService {
    @SystemMessage(
            """
                You are an assistant translator that receives a text and needs to translate it perfectly from one language to another.
                But you need to detect first in which language the text is written.
                If the text is already in the destination language, you should return the original text without any changes.
            """)
    @UserMessage(
            """
                You will receive the text to translate in {text} and will have to translate it to {destination}.
                The text will be in the following format: {text}.
                You should return the translated text in the following format: {translated_text}.
            """)
    String translate(String text, String destination);
}

and my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dwitech.medilingua</groupId>
    <artifactId>medilingua-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <quarkus.version>3.12.0</quarkus.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.4</compiler-plugin.version>
        <quarkus-langchain4j.version>0.15.1</quarkus-langchain4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkiverse.langchain4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-langchain4j-openai</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus-langchain4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

As said, running the code with quarks:dev, I get following error
2024-07-02 07:44:21,732 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor#handleAiServices threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key null (attempted merging values 0 and 1)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor$TemplateParameterInfo.toNameToArgsPositionMap(AiServicesProcessor.java:1221)
    at io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor.gatherSystemMessageInfo(AiServicesProcessor.java:958)
    at io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor.gatherMethodMetadata(AiServicesProcessor.java:877)
    at io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor.handleAiServices(AiServicesProcessor.java:721)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)

    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:331)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:58)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:113)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:435)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:56)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:138)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:93)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:131)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor#handleAiServices threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key null (attempted merging values 0 and 1)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor$TemplateParameterInfo.toNameToArgsPositionMap(AiServicesProcessor.java:1221)
    at io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor.gatherSystemMessageInfo(AiServicesProcessor.java:958)
    at io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor.gatherMethodMetadata(AiServicesProcessor.java:877)
    at io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.deployment.AiServicesProcessor.handleAiServices(AiServicesProcessor.java:721)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)

    at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:123)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:160)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:327)
    ... 9 more

I thought I could solve it using JDK17 instead of JDK21 but to no avail.
Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?
Regards,
D.

The problem is that Quarkus LangChain4j assumes that the compiled code contains the parameter names, which in your configuration is not true.
So you basically need to change maven-compiler-plugin to:
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


Thanks, it solved my problem, now I can continue testing. I would have never caught that by myself.

I have opened a PR to provide a meaningful warning message, because as you said it's totally not obvious what the problem is

Alternatively you can also add the @V annotation onto the parameters: String translate(@V("text") String text, @V("destination") String destination);
